# Changing the state of the CollectionView Cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    //NSLog(@"enter category cell");

    CategoryViewCell* cell = (CategoryViewCell*)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    [cell.imgCat setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[categoryImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];
    [cell.labelCatName setText:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [catName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]] capitalizedString]];
    if([categories[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",(int)indexPath.row]] isEqual:@YES]) {
        //NSLog(@"set border");

        cell.layer.borderColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
        cell.layer.borderWidth = 3;

    }
    return cell;
}

-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CategoryViewCell* cell = (CategoryViewCell*)[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.layer.borderWidth = 3;
    cell.layer.borderColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;

    //NSLog(@"%i", (int)indexPath.item);
    categories[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", (int)indexPath.item]] = @YES;



}

-(void) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didDeselectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    CategoryViewCell* cell = (CategoryViewCell*)[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.layer.borderColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;

    categories[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", (int)indexPath.item]] = @NO;
}
```

The problem:
The above code will show you a collectionView with cells that are selected at default.  However, the states of these selected cells are not selected. So I have to tap twice to deselect them because the first tap is to select them, and second tap is to deselect them.

I have tried to set selected for cell but it doesn't work either.  The cell will have a red border whenever the user selected a cell and clearColor when the user deselect the cell.

I tried:

```
cell.selected = YES;
```

But this permanently gives a collectionView Cell a red border.

And add it in cellForItemAtIndexPath method still doesn't do the trick.

```
[self collectionView:collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

CategoryViewCell.m

```
-(void) setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setSelected:selected];
    //NSLog(@"Pass Select Animated");
    if (selected) {
        self.flagHighlight = NO;
        self.selected = NO;
        self.layer.borderColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
        self.layer.borderWidth = 3;
    } else {
        self.flagHighlight = YES;
        self.selected = YES;
        self.layer.borderColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
        self.layer.borderWidth = 3;
    }
}
```

How would I pre-select a cell when the view is loaded programmatically?
Or even better just change the state of the cell being selected.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since you're using custom `UICollectionViewCell`, firstly, I'd overwrite `setSelected:animated` (or something like that) of it where you set the border color. And then do the `cell.selected = YES` if you need in `collectionView: cellForItemAtIndexPath:`

Comment: I followed the way you approach, however, there are places where I'm not clear, I set self.layer.borderColor and width in my Cell.m. But it doesn't seems to be adding the borders.  Do you have any source code I can take a look? Thanks for your message.

Comment: Could you show what method in CategoryViewCell.m you added?

Comment: Sure, I added the codes above. And in the cellForItemAtIndexPath, I added [cell setSelected:YES animated:NO];.

Answer (score 0):

Ending up answering my own problem.

so I use `[collectionView selectItemAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO scrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionNone];`

in cellForItemAtIndexPath.

Serve the purpose nicely.